# Need help to solve my php mail function query

Tags: php, email

I have a query regarding my email function,
I am working on a panel, where we can send the tour packages details and itinerary directly to the client by entering his email.

My real problem is, some of my tour packages are successfully sent to the client email address while some tour packages give me error while sending.

This is the following error i get while sending the email.
What follows is the last error I get:

```
Array ( [type] => 8 [message] => Undefined variable: message [file] => /home/jonn5/public_html/webapp/includes/download.php [line] => 68 )
```

and below is my code for the mailing purpose:

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
$p5 = $_POST['markup'];
$id = $_POST['packid'];


if(isset($_POST['send_email']))
{
    $id = $_POST['packid'];
    if($_POST['client_email']=='' || $_POST['markup']=='')
    {
        $mailmsg = 'Client email or markup missing';
        echo "<script>alert('Client or Markup Missing');</script>";
        echo "<script>this.window.close();</script>";
    }
    else
    {
$mailmsg='';
$to = $_POST['client_email'];
$p5 = $_POST['markup'];
$subject = 'Tour details';
$agent = $_SESSION['username'];
$queryagent= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM rmt_users where rmt_uname = '$agent'");
while($rsagent=mysqli_fetch_array($queryagent)){
$email = $rsagent['rmt_uemail'];
$imagepath = $rsagent['rmt_ulogo'];
if($imagepath==''){$imagepath='images/logo.png';}
$phone = $rsagent['rmt_uphone'];
}
$result1= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM rmt_tours where p_id = '$id'");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
$p1 = $row1['p_2star'];
$p2 = $row1['p_3star'];
$p3 = $row1['p_4star'];
$p4 = $row1['p_5star'];
$markup = '0.'.$p5;
$r1 = $p1*$markup;
$r1 = $p1+$r1;
$r2 = $p2*$markup;
$r2 = $p2+$r2;
$r3 = $p3*$markup;
$r3 = $p3+$r3;
$r4 = $p4*$markup;
$r4 = $p4+$r4;

$message .='
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td, th {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
text-align: left;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>';  ///this is line 68

$message .='
<table>
<tr><td width="10%"></td><td width="30%"></td><td width="60%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><img src="http://agent.routemate.in/'.$imagepath.'" height="25px" width="auto"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">For Any Query Email us at : <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a> or call us on <a href="tel:'.$phone.'">'.$phone.'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Package ID</td><td>Package Name</td><td>No of Nights</td></tr>
<tr><td>'.$row1["p_id"].'</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_nights"])).'</td><td>'.$row1["p_name"].'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hotel Category</td><td>Hotel Details</td><td>Package Cost</td></tr>';

$message .='
<tr><td>2 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_2star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r1).'</td></tr>';

if($row1['p_3star']!='0')
{
    $message .='
<tr><td>3 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_3star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r2).'</td></tr>';
}

if($row1['p_4star']!='0')
{
    $message .='
<tr><td>4 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_4star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r3).'</td></tr>';
}

if($row1['p_5star']!='0')
{
    $message .='
<tr><td>5 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_5star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r4).'</td></tr>';
}

$message .='<tr><td colspan="3">Destination Details</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Destination Name</td><td>No of Nights</td></tr>';

$b_destinations = json_decode($row1['p_d1']);
$b_nights = json_decode($row1['p_d1n']);

for($i=0;$i<count($b_destinations[0]);$i++)
{
$message .='<tr><td colspan="2">'.$b_destinations[0][$i].'</td><td>'.$b_nights[0][$i].'</td></tr>';
}

$message .='<tr><td>Day</td><td>Itinerary Title</td><td>Itinerary Details</td></tr>';

$titledata = json_decode($row1['p_it_title'] ) ;
$detaildata = json_decode( $row1['p_it_detail'] );

for($i=0;$i<count($titledata[0]);$i++){
    $c = $i+1;
   $message .='<tr><td>Day : '.$c.'</td><td>'.$titledata[0][$i].'</td><td>'.preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s ]/", "", $detaildata[0][$i]).'</td></tr>';
}


$message .='
<tr><td colspan="3">What You Get</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_inclusion"])).'</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">What Excludes</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_exclusion"])).'</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">Places of Intrest</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_other"])).'</td></tr>';


$message .='<tr>
<td colspan="3"><h4>Note : Above Cost is Excluding 5% GST</h4>
<ul>
<li>This is just a quote, no reservations held yet or booking is not proceed yet.</li>
<li>The rooms & rates are subject to availability at the time of booking / confirmation.</li>
<li>Hotel, Sightseeing, Meals, Transfers rate might change without any prior notice until & unless it been booked/ confirmed from your end.</li>
<li>The change in dates and increase or decrease of number of persons will attract re-quote.</li>
<li>Additional Bank charges will be applicable, if payment is made in foreign currency.</li>
<li>The above cost does not include any kind of surcharge if applicable during the given travel period.</li>
<li>Quotation might change due to currencies ROE fluctuation during confirmation & booking process</li>
<li style="color:red;"><b>Important Note</b></li>
<li style="color:red;">No Refund on unutilized services</li>
<li style="color:red;">Rates are valid for Indian nationals only </li>
</ul>

<h4 style="color:red;">Cancellation Policy</h4>
<ul>
<li>90-29 Days: 10% Of The Total Cost</li>
<li>30- 20 Days: 30% Of The Total Cost</li>
<li>20 – 15 Days: 50% Of The Total Cost</li>
<li>15 – 07 Days: 75% Cancellation Will Apply</li>                        
<li>07 – 00 Days: 100% Cancellation Will Apply</li>
<li>No Refund Either In Part Or In Full Will Be Made For Any Unused Part Of The Services provided in the package</li>
<li>Any Refund shall be claimed with in forty five working days</li>
<li>In case of cancellation of reserved tickets from our end you will be charged three hundred rupees per seat for railway tickets and three hundred and fifty rupees for per seat for airline tickets</li> 
 </ul>
<b>For Any Clarification/ Query feel free to contact us.<br>Assuaring You The Best Of Our Service  At All The Time.</b>
</td></tr>';
}

$message .='</table></body></html>';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$from = $_SESSION['email'];
$from = filter_var($from, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

//$from = 'info@routemate.in';

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


// Sending email
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if (!$success) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
    print_r(error_get_last());
}

}
}
```

according to error i have error at the line 68,
but the line 68 only has this

```
$message = '</body>';
```

Why is it happening? some package are sent successfully while some give me this error.

Updated here : for the mail which i get error while sending, i don't what the problem with the mail.
for the package which are send successfully they are sent my the logged in agent's email id, which ever agent is logged in at that time,  mail is sent from the agent's email id,
that the most funny thing is for the tour packages which are giving me this error, i use my local mail id to send email, then those are submitted successfully.
It's brain jamming me.

Comment: Get rid of mixing html + php + mysql.....

Comment: sir then is there any other option to do it, i want to send the tour details directly to the client on his mail id

Answer (score 0):

you having this error because $message is not reachable in that line. beacuse you declare inside `while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))` thisfunction and it is not reachable outside of that function so declare $message at the begining . i think you declared `$mailmsg='';` at the top and forgot to use that and you use $message instead.

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
$p5 = $_POST['markup'];
$id = $_POST['packid'];


if(isset($_POST['send_email']))
{
    $id = $_POST['packid'];
    if($_POST['client_email']=='' || $_POST['markup']=='')
    {
        $mailmsg = 'Client email or markup missing';
        echo "<script>alert('Client or Markup Missing');</script>";
        echo "<script>this.window.close();</script>";
    }
    else
    {
$mailmsg='';
$message='';
$to = $_POST['client_email'];
$p5 = $_POST['markup'];
$subject = 'Tour details';
$agent = $_SESSION['username'];
$queryagent= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM rmt_users where rmt_uname = '$agent'");
while($rsagent=mysqli_fetch_array($queryagent)){
$email = $rsagent['rmt_uemail'];
$imagepath = $rsagent['rmt_ulogo'];
if($imagepath==''){$imagepath='images/logo.png';}
$phone = $rsagent['rmt_uphone'];
}
$result1= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM rmt_tours where p_id = '$id'");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
$p1 = $row1['p_2star'];
$p2 = $row1['p_3star'];
$p3 = $row1['p_4star'];
$p4 = $row1['p_5star'];
$markup = '0.'.$p5;
$r1 = $p1*$markup;
$r1 = $p1+$r1;
$r2 = $p2*$markup;
$r2 = $p2+$r2;
$r3 = $p3*$markup;
$r3 = $p3+$r3;
$r4 = $p4*$markup;
$r4 = $p4+$r4;

$message .='
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td, th {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
text-align: left;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

th, td {
padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>';  ///this is line 68

$message .='
<table>
<tr><td width="10%"></td><td width="30%"></td><td width="60%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><img src="http://agent.routemate.in/'.$imagepath.'" height="25px" width="auto"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">For Any Query Email us at : <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a> or call us on <a href="tel:'.$phone.'">'.$phone.'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Package ID</td><td>Package Name</td><td>No of Nights</td></tr>
<tr><td>'.$row1["p_id"].'</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_nights"])).'</td><td>'.$row1["p_name"].'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hotel Category</td><td>Hotel Details</td><td>Package Cost</td></tr>';

$message .='
<tr><td>2 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_2star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r1).'</td></tr>';

if($row1['p_3star']!='0')
{
    $message .='
<tr><td>3 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_3star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r2).'</td></tr>';
}

if($row1['p_4star']!='0')
{
    $message .='
<tr><td>4 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_4star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r3).'</td></tr>';
}

if($row1['p_5star']!='0')
{
    $message .='
<tr><td>5 Star</td><td>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_5star_detail"])).'</td><td>'.round($r4).'</td></tr>';
}

$message .='<tr><td colspan="3">Destination Details</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Destination Name</td><td>No of Nights</td></tr>';

$b_destinations = json_decode($row1['p_d1']);
$b_nights = json_decode($row1['p_d1n']);

for($i=0;$i<count($b_destinations[0]);$i++)
{
$message .='<tr><td colspan="2">'.$b_destinations[0][$i].'</td><td>'.$b_nights[0][$i].'</td></tr>';
}

$message .='<tr><td>Day</td><td>Itinerary Title</td><td>Itinerary Details</td></tr>';

$titledata = json_decode($row1['p_it_title'] ) ;
$detaildata = json_decode( $row1['p_it_detail'] );

for($i=0;$i<count($titledata[0]);$i++){
    $c = $i+1;
   $message .='<tr><td>Day : '.$c.'</td><td>'.$titledata[0][$i].'</td><td>'.preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s ]/", "", $detaildata[0][$i]).'</td></tr>';
}


$message .='
<tr><td colspan="3">What You Get</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_inclusion"])).'</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">What Excludes</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_exclusion"])).'</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">Places of Intrest</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row1["p_other"])).'</td></tr>';


$message .='<tr>
<td colspan="3"><h4>Note : Above Cost is Excluding 5% GST</h4>
<ul>
<li>This is just a quote, no reservations held yet or booking is not proceed yet.</li>
<li>The rooms & rates are subject to availability at the time of booking / confirmation.</li>
<li>Hotel, Sightseeing, Meals, Transfers rate might change without any prior notice until & unless it been booked/ confirmed from your end.</li>
<li>The change in dates and increase or decrease of number of persons will attract re-quote.</li>
<li>Additional Bank charges will be applicable, if payment is made in foreign currency.</li>
<li>The above cost does not include any kind of surcharge if applicable during the given travel period.</li>
<li>Quotation might change due to currencies ROE fluctuation during confirmation & booking process</li>
<li style="color:red;"><b>Important Note</b></li>
<li style="color:red;">No Refund on unutilized services</li>
<li style="color:red;">Rates are valid for Indian nationals only </li>
</ul>

<h4 style="color:red;">Cancellation Policy</h4>
<ul>
<li>90-29 Days: 10% Of The Total Cost</li>
<li>30- 20 Days: 30% Of The Total Cost</li>
<li>20 – 15 Days: 50% Of The Total Cost</li>
<li>15 – 07 Days: 75% Cancellation Will Apply</li>                        
<li>07 – 00 Days: 100% Cancellation Will Apply</li>
<li>No Refund Either In Part Or In Full Will Be Made For Any Unused Part Of The Services provided in the package</li>
<li>Any Refund shall be claimed with in forty five working days</li>
<li>In case of cancellation of reserved tickets from our end you will be charged three hundred rupees per seat for railway tickets and three hundred and fifty rupees for per seat for airline tickets</li> 
 </ul>
<b>For Any Clarification/ Query feel free to contact us.<br>Assuaring You The Best Of Our Service  At All The Time.</b>
</td></tr>';
}

$message .='</table></body></html>';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$from = $_SESSION['email'];
$from = filter_var($from, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

//$from = 'info@routemate.in';

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


// Sending email
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if (!$success) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
    print_r(error_get_last());
}

}
}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: abhinav i have already tried that,  i have around 300 tour packages, in which some tour packages are sent successfully on mail, but some get this error, even it doesn't show what is is proper error.

Comment: $mailmsg is show the agent that you have forgot to enter the recepients email id,  $message is the variable where the html body is stored

Comment: try initializing $message=''; before  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                {

Comment: i have tried everything, as i said early also, it's working for some package, but gives error for some packages.

Comment: it is because sometimes that quuery is failing and it is not returning anything. so the compailer not perform while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) . and you are initialising message inside that loop. so it will give error undefined index $message.

Comment: the query is running successfully,  this error is really brain jamming,  i will explain you, 1) there are more than 300 tour packages, in which near about 20-30 packages are giving error while sending, the rest tour packages get send successfully through mail,  2) the packages getting failed, i i remove the agent email, and use my own server email for sending, then this packages get submitted successfully, like $from = agentemail id i changed it to $from = info@routemate.in, then the email gets submitted.

Comment: more tricky, in my php code you can see this code .preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s ]/", "", $detaildata[0][$i]).     also   if  i remove only this code, then also the email gets submitted.  so it really make a confusion why it's happening.

Comment: can you send the data coming in $queryagent for testing purpose?